# authorization in asp.net mvc 4 web api

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api

I've been following a series of videos on [how to create a web API using MVC 4](http://www.asp.net/web-api/videos). The sixth video describes the authorization process, but it is both too complex for what I want, and it somehow redirects to a form (which makes no sense to me, but then I'm new to this stuff).

I've used API's from other sites, and they usually use one of 2 methods:

1. a token in the url (http://myurl/api/service/?token=[bunch of characters here]
2. a username or password (or token) in the header

I'm leaning towards the second method, as it means I wouldn't have to add a parameter to each of my methods.

If I use this approach, do I need to add code to the beginning of each method to check the headers (request.headers?) for username/password (then find them in our database and see if they have permission to access this method)...Or is there a simpler way of doing this?

Comment: Give more thought to your tagging, things like web and api are useless.  You had used asp which resolves to asp-classic.  Hence your original tagging got your question no where near anybody who might help you.

Comment: didn't notice the asp-classic...thanks for the advice

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can mark your Controller class with attribute which is derived from AthorizationFilterAttribute. 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.http.filters.authorizationfilterattribute(v=vs.108).aspx

In this case you will not need to write authorization checks in every method, but only in one place.
This approach is well described under the following link:

http://www.tugberkugurlu.com/archive/api-key-authorization-through-query-string-in-asp-net-web-api-authorizationfilterattribute

Comment: I checked out the second link and its almost exactly what I'm looking for (though slightly more robust than I need it to be). I didn't want to install it as a package (not too familiar with C#) so I decided to copy the parts of the package that I needed and add them to my solution (not very elegant)...ran across a major problem...[Common library was removed](http://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/SourceControl/network/forks/marcind/marcind/changeset/changes/387212fd633c) ...and therefore Error is inaccessible? what do I use instead?

Comment: To be clear, I'm getting the error "'System.Web.Http.Error' is inaccessible due to its protection level"...so, it is now in System.Web.Http (not Common) but it is internal...what should I be using instead?

Comment: Don't you want just copy dlls from the package and reference without modification. The dlls are: System.Web.Http.dll, System.Web.Http.Common.dll, System.Web.Http.WebHost.dll, System.Json.dll, System.Net.Http.dll, System.Net.Http.Formatting.dll, System.Net.Http.WebRequest.dll

Comment: This probably exposes my ignorance, but I wanted to understand exactly what was happening, and there was a lot of stuff in Tugberk's code that I didn't understand...so I wrote some code myself..I was able to combine parts of [Tugberk's Code](https://github.com/tugberkugurlu/ASPNETWebAPISamples/tree/master/TugberkUg.Web.Http/src/TugberkUg.Web.Http) with a [tutorial on filters](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/older-versions/controllers-and-routing/understanding-action-filters-cs) and make a basic authorization without the roles...just the apiKey (i'm now working on adding the roles...)